# Passing data from GSP to a controller in Grails

Tags: grails

I create a GSP page with controls depending on the rows in a database.
This depends on the value returned by the `<g:each in="${Vehicles}" var="vehicle">`
So, if there are 3 vehicles, 3 rows with text boxes will be generated. (The maximum can be 200)

```
<g:form action="update" >
      <label for="SearchTerm">${term}</label>

          <g:each in="${Vehicles}" var="vehicle">
            <tr>
                     <td> <label for="Name">${vehicle.name}</label> </td>
                     <td><g:textField name="${vehicle.id}.ModelNo" /> </td>
                     <td><g:textField name="${vehicle.id}.Year" /> </td>
            </tr>
          </g:each>
  <td> <g:submitButton name="update" value="Update"/></td>
  </g:form>
```

How can I basically pass this value to my controller so that I can then save/update the data to the database. or Is there any easy way to achieve this scenario?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need some code like this in the GSP

```
    <g:form action="update" >
          <label for="SearchTerm">${term}</label>

              <g:each in="${Vehicles}" var="vehicle" status="i">
                <tr>
                         <td> <label for="Name">${vehicle.name}</label> </td>
                         <td><g:hiddenField name="vehicle[${i}].id" value="${vehicle.id}"/>
<g:textField name="vehicle[${i}].ModelNo" value="${vehicle.ModelNo}"/> </td>
                         <td><g:textField name="vehicle[${i}].Year" value="${vehicle.Year}"/> </td>
                </tr>
              </g:each>
      <td> <g:submitButton name="update" value="Update"/></td>
    </g:form>
```

The Controller needs to either have a Domain with a List Property or a Command Object with a List Property ie

```
SearchCommand {   
  List<Vehicle> vehicle = new Arraylist<Vehicle>(3); 
}
```

Then in the controller (if using the command object)

```
def save = {SearchCommand searchCmd-> 
  searchCmd.vehicle.each {vehicle ->
     /* Process Vehicle */
  }
}
```

Hope that Helps

Comment: what can you use besides a hidden form field?

Comment: The HiddenField is probably not needed unless you are going to look up the original item (Vehicle) buy id in the the controller.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the request object from your controller. If you can generate the names of the controls you need to access do something like the following

```
idList.each {
theYear=request.getParameter(it+Year)
}
```

If you want a list of all your generated form fields use something like

```
java.util.Enumeration theFields=request.getParameterNames()
theFields.each {
//look at your field name and take appropriate action
}
```

For more info on the request object see [this](http://www.gulland.com/courses/JavaServerPages/jsp_objects.jsp)