# Creating ICal with plugin, only seems to download, can't figure how to attach to send mail function

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

Standard Grails Mail Plugin [Mail-Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/mail)

ICal Plugin for creating ICal files [I-Cal-Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/ic-alendar)

I've used mail successfully with great ease, attatching files etc, however, getting Ical to work with the `attachBytes` from `mail plugin` is proving difficult

```
sendMail {
            multipart true
            to test@test.com
            subject "whatever..."
            html g.render(template:"/emails/Attendees", model:[ instance: inst])
            inline "banner",  "image/jpeg", new File("./web-app/images/emailTemplates/email_banner.png")
            inline "footer",  "image/jpeg", new File("./web-app/images/emailTemplates/lEdvn.png")
         }
```

To attach files you use `attachBytes` which I was trying to use the standard example `render` function found on the example of the `ical docs`

```
   def ical = render(contentType: 'text/calendar', filename: '<optional filename>') {
                calendar {
                    events {
                        event(start: Date.parse('dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm', '31.10.2009 14:00'),
                                end: Date.parse('dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm', '31.10.2009 15:00'),
                                description: 'Events description',
                                summary: 'Short info1') {
                                    organizer(name: 'Silvio Wangler', email: 'a@b.com')
                                }
                          }
              }
  }
```

The `def ical` technically doesn't matter still renders i.e. immediately downloads upon reaching this code block. The idea is to save and attach to the email, no download.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyone that stumbles across this post this is the answer:

```
def builder = new ICalendarBuilder()

builder.calendar {
events {
    event(start: new Date(), end: (new Date()).next(), summary: 'Text') {
        organizer(name:'Silvio', email:'test@test.com')
        reminder(minutesBefore: 15, description: 'Alarm 123')
    }
  }
}
```

Then for the email `sendMail` function add:

```
attachBytes "appointment.ics", "text/calendar", builder.cal.toString().getBytes('UTF-8')
```

Comment: He can u tell me how did u take the input from the view and what did u do in the controller to extract the information and store it in the database. I guess the things are similar to the multipart request where we take the file as input and then extract the byte file to store it in the database. Can u please make ht things more clear

Comment: @PranavShukla It seems as though you don't understand how to send data from your GSP page/template to the controller, check the docs  or see : [GSP to Controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448681/passing-data-from-gsp-to-a-controller-in-grails) ..... As for the rest of your question I don't quite understand what you want :/